# Titanium IPhone module

Tags: xcode, module, delegates, google-analytics, titanium-mobile

this is the first time I'm developing titanium module for IPhone. I'm working on building Google Analytics module for IPhone.

If I were to implement Google Analytics using XCode, I could just use **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** delegate. Below is the example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
         // Override point for customization after application launch.
         id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXXXXXX-X"];
          return YES;
  }
```

which I tried and it worked perfectly for me.

When it comes to Titanium Module, I think there is no delegate such as didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

I put it in the **startup** function as below:

```
-(void)startup
{
    // this method is called when the module is first loaded
    // you *must* call the superclass
    [super startup];
        id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-38803610-1"];
    NSLog(@"[INFO] %@ loaded",self);
 }
```

but when I execute my application like below:

```
var mod = require("com.mymodule")
Ti.API.log("The module: " +  mod)
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
: Dispatcher initialization failed: Error Domain=com.google.analytics.error Code=1 "Dispatcher must be initialized on main thread." UserInfo=0xb3d1270 {NSLocalizedDescription=Dispatcher must be initialized on main thread.}
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the UI task in main thread. You can do that using:

`ENSURE_UI_THREAD(functionName,args);`

and

```
ENSURE_UI_THREAD_0_ARGS
```

Please check this [iOS Module Development Guide](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide) for more similar methods

Comment: @senthil: with pleasure :)